# Trying to make an array of car objects, getting null

Tags: java, arrays, object

My program allows the user to change the make of the car.  I want to make an array of 2 cars.  I declare an array using `Car[] driving = new Car[2]`.  Then in the constructor make their objects `driving[0] = new Car()` and `driving[1] = new Car()`.  I am not sure if this is the proper way of doing this since running my program gives me a NullPointerException.

Driver class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int choice;
    static Car[] driving = new Car[2];
    public Driver(){
        driving[0] = new Car();
        driving[1] = new Car();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
            changeSettings();
        }
    static public void changeSettings(){

        System.out.println("Enter the make");
        driving[0].setMake(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

Car class:

```
public class Car
{
    private String make;

    public Car(){
        make = "Mercedes";
    }

    public String getMake(){
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make){
        this.make = make;
    } 
}
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Driver.changeSettings(Driver.java:23)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:18)
```

It looks like the errors are at lines 18 and 23 but I can't think of a solution.  Is my way to making the car objects acceptable?

Comment: I think the problem is with the sc.nextLine() you were instantiating the sc as an static field which gets system.in as the input I was wondering whether it is going to be called in the right place or not! may just init sc before the driving[0].setMake(...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the changeSettings method without ever calling the Driver constructor. But your main problem comes from mixing static and non-static code as you're doing it.

- Get rid of all static methods and fields, other than the main method.
- Create a Driver instance in main and assign it to a variable called driver.
- Again, make `changeSettings an instance (non-static method).
- In main then call the Driver's non-static changeSettings method on your driver variable.

For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver
{
    // static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // static int choice;
    // static Car[] driving = new Car[2];
    private Car[] driving = new Car[2];

    public Driver(){
        driving[0] = new Car();
        driving[1] = new Car();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
       Driver driver = new Driver();
       driver.changeSettings();
    }

    public void changeSettings(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the make");
        driving[0].setMake(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see... for some reason I thought it would be automatically called.

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt: it's key to remember that the JVM is literal and dumb -- it only does exactly what you tell it to do, no more and no less. Still, your biggest mistake in that code, per my eye, is that you're over-using static.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  But is it ok to use static if I want particular field or object accessible throughout the whole class?

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt: that is a bad reason to make something static. It should be static if it is to be a property of the class, not the object, if it is a constant, or if it is a utility method.

Comment: Ok but the scanner for example, isn't that a utility, and I wish to use it in other methods.  Seems weird to declare it at the beginning of every method rather than using static Scanner.

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt: then declare Scanner as a non-static field, and then it will be available for use in other methods, but just don't make it static.